# Flutter : get Shared Preference items from class into stateless Widget Edit #1

Tags: flutter, fetch, sharedpreferences

I have file called services contain all functions ,on of them is to get shared preference data ,and it is like this :

```
class Services {
var name;
  var phone;
  get_user() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    name = pref.getString('name');
    phone = pref.getString('phone');
    return {'name': name, 'phone': phone};
  }
}
```

I am try to call it in stateless Widget as this with Future builder:

```
    class Home extends StatelessWidget {
      var name;
      var phone;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Services().get_user(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            var name = snapshot.data[0].name; // I used this also : var name = snapshot.data[0]['name'];
      print(name);
```

when I used  var name = snapshot.data[0].name I get :`The getter 'name' was called on null`.

and if I used var name = snapshot.data[0]['name'] I get : `The method '[]' was called on null`.

but the print(snapshot.data); is printed fine : `{name: sar, phone: 12345}` .

Comment: if you have a `Future` (since `get_user`  returns a `Future`) use `FutureBuilder` widget in your `build()` method

Comment: @pskink I guess that ,the problem I have another Future builder at same page ,the solution may be to use statefull widget and use shared preference with setstate ,many thanks

Comment: you dont need any `setState` - just return `FutureBuilder` from `build()` method and pass your `Future` as a `future:` parameter

Comment: setState tells the whole screen to rebuild all of its widgets. The print 2 prints null because it didn't wait for Services().get_user().then to finish. Have a look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc . Learn how to use async and await

Comment: @pskink ok I will do that

Comment: @pskink I tried that and get another error ,I edited the question ,if you can help

Comment: `snapshot.data['name']`

Comment: opps ,is that because I didn't return a list ? Thank You it is worked

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to return in the `snapshot` is a Map and not a List. To access the object, you can call it using the key `snapshot.data['name']`